Is there anyway I can have synchronized height when boxes height change based on filters?
I am making a comparison UI. I want to align every left item with the right one. Sometimes one side div can be empty as content changes based on the filter but it still should take the same space as the other side so that every other item aligns with each other.
Here is a snippet of replicating the issue in plain HTML/CSS/Javascript so when I am removing the item from the boxes the height is not adapting.


 function setEqualHeights() {
        const items = [
          "first-item",
          "second-item",
          "third-item",
          "fourth-item",
        ];
        items.forEach((item) => {
          const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.${item}`);
          let maxHeight = 0;
          elements.forEach((el) => {
            el.style.height = "auto";
            const height = el.offsetHeight;
            if (height > maxHeight) {
              maxHeight = height;
              1;
            }
          });
          elements.forEach((el) => {
            el.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`;
          });
        });
      }

      window.addEventListener("load", setEqualHeights);
      window.addEventListener("resize", setEqualHeights);
.first-item {
        height: var(--first-item-height);
      }

      .second-item {
        height: var(--second-item-height);
      }

      .third-item {
        height: var(--third-item-height);
      }

      .fourth-item {
        height: var(--fourth-item-height);
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
      <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="border first-item">
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border second-item">
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third-item"></div>
        <div class="border fourth-item">
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            first <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="border first-item">
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-item"></div>
        <div class="border third-item">
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border fourth-item">
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            second <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



For complexity in data passing, I can't change the HTML structure and have similar items in a div.
So I am now synchronizing height with JavaScript. I am somewhat successful with the synchronizing part.
But when UI changes based on the filters, the height of the boxes is not adapting.
I have tried setting minHeight is helps when height increases but does not help when height decreases.
Also tried to set the height auto temporarily before and after setting the fixed height but not working properly.

Frankly though, this sounds like something for CSS-Grid but a demo is required.

@Paulie_D Thanks, I have added a snippet reproducing the issue in raw HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Would highly appreciate your help.

Still not clear on what effect you are trying to achieve here.

@Paulie_D Sorry, basically what I want is the height of the row(left and right side boxes) height always should be the same and always should be the maximum height. So that first-item aligns with first-item and second-item with second-item. Even if I remove the item with the remove button click or filter items from the boxes(list of divs). But now if I remove the items the height doesn't adapt. Hope it makes it a bit clear.
